# Create resizable plot layout with different sized sections in Bokeh

Tags: python, layout, data-visualization, bokeh

Can I create a Bokeh layout where the widgets section is set to be e.g. 10% of the screen height with plot section at 90%?

I'm trying to avoid manually re-sizing my plot and using `sizing_mode='fixed'` which wouldn't work with resizing the browser window.

Currently have:

```
layout = layout(
    [plot],
    [[button, slider]],
    sizing_mode='stretch_both'
)
```

In this case, the bottom half of screen is filled entirely by the stretched button/slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently (as of 1.3.4) no mechanism to specify a *percentage*, but you can put the widgets in a `row` and give that a fixed height while letting the plot vary. Here is one way:

```
layout = column(
    plot, 
    row(button, slider, height=100, sizing_mode="stretch_width"), 
    sizing_mode="stretch_both"
)
```